# How can I exchange data via IP on my T-Mobile cell phone?

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I have multiple T-Mobile Android cell phones and I am writing an app to go on all the phones that exchanges data via IP.  Is there a way to get the private IP addresses of the cellular connections, and send data to each phone using those addresses?

Comment: how much data? are the phones in proximity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wish to create some kind of intermediary web service that all of the devices talk to to share their IPs. Some kind of simple, RESTful API that I device could call to POST their IP/MEID and fetch the other devices' IPs.

You can use [something like this](http://www.droidnova.com/get-the-ip-address-of-your-device,304.html) to get your device IP.